# c++ g++ llvm-clang compiler profiling

Tags: c++, g++, clang

Note, my question is not: how do I tell my compiler to compile with profiling on.

I want to *profile* my compiles process. For each file, I'd like to know how much time is spent on *each* line of the program.

I'm working on a project, some files have huge compile times, I'm trying to figure out why.

Is there anyway to do this with g++ or llvm-clang?

Thanks!

Output of -v -ftime-report (what oes it mean)?

In the following, is "parser" or "expand" the use of templates?

```
Execution times (seconds)
  callgraph construction:   0.06 ( 2%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.09 ( 2%) wall    3181 kB ( 1%) ggc
  callgraph optimization:   0.05 ( 2%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 1%) wall    5243 kB ( 2%) ggc
  cfg cleanup           :   0.02 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall      11 kB ( 0%) ggc
  df live regs          :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
  df reg dead/unused notes:   0.03 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 1%) wall    1993 kB ( 1%) ggc
  register information  :   0.04 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.04 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
  alias analysis        :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall     450 kB ( 0%) ggc
  rebuild jump labels   :   0.03 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
  preprocessing         :   0.12 ( 4%) usr   0.06 (12%) sys   1.46 (27%) wall    2752 kB ( 1%) ggc
  parser                :   0.67 (21%) usr   0.15 (29%) sys   0.89 (16%) wall   91749 kB (36%) ggc
  name lookup           :   0.15 ( 5%) usr   0.12 (24%) sys   0.24 ( 4%) wall   14384 kB ( 6%) ggc
  inline heuristics     :   0.03 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
  tree gimplify         :   0.06 ( 2%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.09 ( 2%) wall   15992 kB ( 6%) ggc
  tree eh               :   0.02 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.03 ( 1%) wall    4405 kB ( 2%) ggc
  tree CFG construction :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.03 ( 1%) wall    6636 kB ( 3%) ggc
  tree CFG cleanup      :   0.02 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall      15 kB ( 0%) ggc
  tree find ref. vars   :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall    1870 kB ( 1%) ggc
  tree SSA rewrite      :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall    2357 kB ( 1%) ggc
  tree SSA other        :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall      37 kB ( 0%) ggc
  tree operand scan     :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.04 ( 8%) sys   0.06 ( 1%) wall    6340 kB ( 2%) ggc
  tree SSA to normal    :   0.05 ( 2%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 1%) wall      95 kB ( 0%) ggc
  dominance computation :   0.04 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.04 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
  expand                :   0.60 (18%) usr   0.03 ( 6%) sys   0.71 (13%) wall   45557 kB (18%) ggc
  varconst              :   0.02 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall    3532 kB ( 1%) ggc
  jump                  :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall    1745 kB ( 1%) ggc
  mode switching        :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
  integrated RA         :   0.35 (11%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.35 ( 6%) wall    5259 kB ( 2%) ggc
  reload                :   0.29 ( 9%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.31 ( 6%) wall    6490 kB ( 3%) ggc
  thread pro- & epilogue:   0.10 ( 3%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.13 ( 2%) wall    4832 kB ( 2%) ggc
  final                 :   0.19 ( 6%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.21 ( 4%) wall    2985 kB ( 1%) ggc
  symout                :   0.25 ( 8%) usr   0.01 ( 2%) sys   0.26 ( 5%) wall   27322 kB (11%) ggc
  TOTAL                 :   3.25             0.51             5.49             256741 kB
```

Comment: This is the best you can get. It's impossible to see the time of individual C++ lines but here you can see if the problem is with the preprocessor, or parser or any of the other compiler steps.

Your file was compiled in just 3.25 seconds.

Comment: From this short run time you cannot draw any meaningful conclusions! Accumulate these times over all compiles!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try these command line options with g++

> -v -ftime-report

That should give you more information on the compiling process. The culprit is usually templates though.

Comment: As a last resort you can comment stuff out in order to find what is taking the most time.

Answer (score 2):

For preprocessing line a bit longer suggestion:

" 0.12 ( 4%) usr   0.06 (12%) sys   1.46 (27%) wall " - this line says, that preprocessing was to do small job on CPU itself (0.12), but is uses system calls rather heavy (0.06 or 50% of user CPU time) and the most time was wasted not on CPU (1.46 real time >> 0.18 s cpu time). So This time was wasted in waiting an I/O operation OR waiting for CPU on busy system. Was this run the only working program on the machine?

For I/O you can do: add noatime to fs to lower number of I/O reqs, buy faster (in terms of lower seek time or higher IO rate) HDD, move clang sources to SSD or even RAM-drive (loop-device). And you can't do a defragment, because it is linux.

For meaning of eash pass, use http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Passes.html#Passes

Comment: For meaning of lines: Short introduction into gcc http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~uday/gcc-mini-workshop/gcc-internals-1.pdf Presentation about RTL http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/gcc-workshop-09/downloads/gccw09-rtl.pdf