# Profiling C++ code compilation speed

Tags: c++, compilation, profiling

How would you get some kind of objective measurement if physical structure of a C++ project is good for compilation speed? Some people say you should avoid templates for better compilation speed, but then if the templates generate a lot of non-redundant object code even if lines/sec compilation speed isn't great it's not really bad. So you can't really check lines/sec between two projects to get a good idea if the structure is good, plus many other factors could twist the results anyway.

Would the amount of generated object code per second be a good measure (obviously on same platform & compiler)? Or are there some code analysis tools for this? It would be interesting to get some kind of objective measurement of the physical structure to know if there's some room for improvements. E.g. if you should try to further optimize header file dependencies or group more code to cpp files (ala unity builds), move more stuff from headers to cpp, etc.

Comment: I have the instinct that this question is off topic for its broadness and therefore may be closed but it's a very good question.

Comment: I wonder - are there code repositories of problems being solved with different approaches?  _Complicated thing, solved with templates_ vs. _solved with #defines_...

Comment: Some time ago I was using a template construct in header files which in one instance noticeably slowed down compilation speed, so the culprit was kind of easy to spot, narrow down and get fixed (still using templates but was able to move the definition from header to a cpp file). I'm just wondering if I have other but less obvious issues there and it's kind of hard to tell without some way to analyze the project with some reference values.

Comment: I don't think you can get any insights without real tests. Benchmark it, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542273/c-g-llvm-clang-compiler-profiling

Comment: @usr1234567 Benchmarking alone isn't enough though because you must be able to somehow compare against other projects how your project is performing. Nice link though for getting breakdown of the compilation performance at different stages.

Comment: It's a somewhat interesting question, but really, it's been decades since computer time was more expensive than programmer time. If templates or some other language feature save hours of programmer time at the expense of a few more minutes to compile, well then, use them!

Comment: It's not unfortunately as simple as that. When the compilation and link time is reduced it saves programmer time. This isn't really the matter of using templates or not. It's more about knowing if there is something to improve to bring down compilation time.

Comment: Amount of object code generated per unit time would not be a good measure, because templates can greatly inflate the amount of object code - and templates with a common implementation would provide the same or better program without most of the extra object code.

Comment: If it is just to improve the compilation time, I'd try to speed up the compiler without limiting language featurs. First things coming to my mind are: Use -O0 (many stick with autotools' default -O2), use precompiled headers, use ccache, use multithreading in your make files, set up distributed compiling infrastructure, use Single Compilation Unit (recently I read about compiling Clang within 3 minutes instead of 29 min), use faster compiler (Clang over Gcc)

Comment: @WarrenDew yeah it's not perfect. Maybe I could run the generated object code through something which checks repetitive sequences in object code to bias the result (just brainstorming). Actually some entropy encoder like used in zip would do that

Comment: @usr1234567 I have pretty much exhausted all those options (except in VC domain). But the issue is really that I don't know if the compilation speed is good or not or if there are some things in code that slow things down that could be improved. It's more of a blind guess work right now and it takes quite a lot of effort to try various things out. If I'm already within 10% from the optimal compilation why bother, but if I'm using some construct which brings the compilation speed down by 50% I should address that. But at the moment it's impossible to tell without some objective benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at counting instantiations. There is a template profiler tool for boost which can do this:

https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/tools/profile_templates/

If you're using visual studio 2010 or later, then you might be able to used an extension called Meta which handles some of the complexity of invoking the boost profiler tool.

Here's a link to the visual studio 2010 extension.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/325d7305-2787-4b1d-9ac7-743e3d767531

Source code is here for a vs 2013 version:
https://github.com/brandon-kohn/Meta