# Massive difference in Template instantiation times between MSVC and AppleClang

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compilation, clang

Analysing build times of the same project using MSVC vs AppleClang14 and I notice that some of the templated functions on clang can take up to 4 seconds, where the longest it would take on MSVC is ~20ms

Does anyone know what would cause such a massive difference?

Used build analysis on clang and analysis tools in visual studio and compared the results.

Comment: Have you broken down the build times into individual passes yet?  eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542273/c-g-llvm-clang-compiler-profiling with a simple cpp file that instantiates just one template

Comment: I think there is an internal identifier difference, msvc use uuid (Fixed size), whereas gcc/clang use full mangling name, which might become huge with template.

Comment: @Jarod42 interesting, but when we build with flags like d2cgsummary and d2 i think it was, we see the full names as identifiers. Or would these be mapped back from UUID in the output of these tools?